# C# Web service works in console but not from asp.net website on IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm using a web service which works fine when I run it on my machine in an ASP.NET application using the default IIS Express VS 2010 comes with. However, when I move it to our server with IIS I get the error:

> Error: There was no endpoint listening at 'web service name here' that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

'web service name here' is just a placeholder I put for this post. It has the right web service name.

So I pulled out the small login code that this is failing on into a console application and ran that from the IIS server and it worked! So I have to assume this is some kind of permissions issue with the IIS server on how it's running my web service code? In my ASP.NET program I have a separate DLL that handles the web service. The ASP.NET application fires off a separate thread that uses the DLL I made that uses the web service. Is it something to do with the separate thread permissions maybe? Any ideas?

Comment: `'web service name here'` is ringing alarm bells. Is it really saying that verbatim? This should be the real endpoint whereas this looks like a place-holder?

Comment: No, I just didn't want to show the web service name. It has the right name for the web service.

Comment: You may want to highlight that because the answer below is valid **IF** this is what it says. You should make it clearer that you have changed the output!

Comment: Added detail explaining that. I thought it was obvious but I can see the confusion. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step when faced with this sort of issue is to search your config files for "web service name here" (or if this isn't actually the message you're getting the address given in the message). My suspicion is somewhere you'll have a WCF reference set up which needs a proper IP address.

Once you've got the address (assuming it looks valid) you need to check you can access it from the machine which is having the difficulties - it may be a firewall issue.

Now that you've established that your console application is connecting correctly from the same machine the next step is to check that both your IIS App Pool and Console application are running under the same user account/permissions. It may be that one identity has permission to access the network/internet and the other one doesn't.

Comment: I just did that for the post. It actually has the right name of the web service.

Comment: @user441521 I've just expanded, it sounds like the firewall is preventing access. Can you access the service from the machine through a browser?

Comment: In my post I mentioned that I made a C# console application with the same code and it works. That's what is leading me to believe it's some kind of IIS issue.

Comment: @user441521 - expanded again, are they running as the same user?

Comment: When I run the console app I'm logged in as myself. Looks like the pool is running as ApplicationPoolIdentity. I've never messed with this before. Will have to test with my login to see if that makes the difference. Ideally I don't want my ID used, so maybe I'll have to figure out why ApplicationPoolIdentity can't get outside the proxy.

Comment: Interesting it doesn't take my login when I set a custom account. Says the password is incorrect, which I test on the intranet site and it's not incorrect. Not sure why this server when setting the pool identity won't let me use my account.

Comment: Since we narrowed it down I'll say you got the answer and make a new post that is more specific. Thanks.